# FFMPEG: How to add volume to filter complex

Tags: audio, filter, ffmpeg, volume

This is my filter complex script:

`-filter_complex "[0:a]highpass=f=200,lowpass=f=3000[mic];[mic][1:a]amix=duration=shortest[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]"`

I would like to add in here volume steering for each audio (there are two)
I know that "volume=0.5" should be added there somewhere but i don't know where. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two instances of [volume](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) filter:

```
-filter_complex "[0:a]highpass=f=200,lowpass=f=3000,volume=0.5[mic];[1:a]volume=0.5[a1];[mic][a1]amix=duration=shortest[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]"
```